# Animated sequence using uislider

Tags: jquery

ive just started learning jquery and im struggling. Im trying to create an offline page that  incorporated a uislider that links a series of images (frames) so when the slider is dragged it creates an animation. . I would like to  check a local folder if possible and use all images in that folder as apposed to listing the images in html as there will be over 200 images. I would also like the position of the slider to be remembered between webpages and refresh as I would like to have different different views of the same animation.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

below works as it should using gsap but I need to implement a way to save the state on refresh and between pages?

```
  <div id="wrapper">
  <div id="demoWrapper">
  <div id='image'>
  <img src="" /> >
  <img src="" /> 
  <img src="" />     
  </div>

  <div id="sliderWrapper">
  <div id="slider"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div id="nav-bar">
  <button id="play">play</button>
  <button id="pause">pause</button>
  <button id="reverse">reverse</button>
  <button id="restart">restart</button>
  </div>

  </div>

  $(document).ready(function() {

  var images = $('#image').children(), // images in the sequence
  fps = 1,
  duration = 1 / fps;

  var tl = new TimelineLite({

  onUpdate:updateSlider})
 .staggerTo(images, 0, {position: 'static', visibility: 'visible' },       duration, 0)
.staggerTo(images.not(images.last()), 0, {position: 'absolute',     visibility: 'hidden', immediateRender: false }, duration, duration)
.set({}, {}, "+="+duration);





 $("#play").click(function() {
 //play() only plays forward from current position. If timeline has     finished, play() has nowhere to go.
  //if the timeline is not done then play() or else restart() (restart   always restarts from the beginning).

  if(tl.progress() != 1){

    tl.play();
 } else {
 tl.restart();
 }
 });

 $("#pause").click(function() {
    tl.pause();
  });

 $("#reverse").click(function() {
    tl.reverse();
 });



  $("#restart").click(function() {
    tl.restart();
  });       


 $("#slider").slider({
 range: "max",
 min: 0,
 max: 100,
  step:1, 
 slide: function ( event, ui ) {
 tl.pause();
//adjust the timeline's progress() based on slider value
 tl.progress( ui.value/100 );

}
}); 



 function updateSlider() {
 $("#slider").slider("value", tl.progress() *100);
 }
});
```